# Injectivity of an integral operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

we have the following integral operator:

> $T:C^0[0,1] \rightarrow C^0[0,1]$, with $Tu(x)=e^x \int_{0}^{x}e^{-t}u(t)dt$.

This operator is not injective since I found $Tu(x)=0$ for $u(t)=e^t(2t-x)$. So $\ker(T) \ne \langle {\vec 0} \rangle$, thus it's not injective.

Am I wrong?

Comment: It's wrong because it is meaningless : your function $u$ must depend either on $x$ or on $t$, not both...

Comment: On a different level, had you worked in $C^1$, i.e., considered $T:u \in C^1 \to v \in C^1$ (with the same definition), the operator is a bijection because it has an inverse which is $T^{-1}: v \to u = v' - v$ (I discovered it using Laplace Transform)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong ! Your function $u$ contains the parameter $x$. $u$ has to be independent of $x$.

$T$ is injective. To this end let $u \in C^0[0,1]$ and $Tu=0$.
 This means that

$e^x \int_{0}^{x}e^{-t}u(t)dt=0$ for all $x \in [0,1].$

Hence $\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t}u(t)dt=0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ and therefore $\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t}u(t)dt=e^{-x}u(x)=0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Conclusion: $u(x)=0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks. The issue was that the extremal of the integral was coincident with the parameter.